# Having trouble binding data imported from Firebase with *ngFor

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I can't figure out how to get my data to show up in my template.  I added a `console.log()` to the `ngOnInit` of my component to make sure the service was retrieving and delivering the data and sure enough I get a result.

In the `elements` part of the console I see this in the places where the data should be populating.

```
<!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object]"
}-->
```

When I change names around in the binding trying to see if I need to order them differently I start getting undefined errors.  However going back to how I have it now everything works fine aside from not displaying the data.

Here's my app component

```
import { Component, OnInit }                    from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable }  from 'angularfire2';

import { FirebaseService }                      from './services/database.service';



export interface answers {
    $key: string;
    id: string;
    answer: string;
}

export interface questions {
    $key: string;
    question: string;
    id: string;
    name: string;
    answers: answers[];
}

export interface bus_image {
    $key: string;
    questions: questions[];
}

@Component({
    moduleId:       module.id,
    selector:       'app-root',
    templateUrl:    './app.component.html',
    styleUrls:      [ './app.component.css' ],
    providers:      [ FirebaseService ]
})



export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    title = 'app works!';
    businessImage: bus_image;

    constructor(private _firebaseService:FirebaseService){}

    ngOnInit() {
        this._firebaseService.getBusImg().subscribe(businessImage => {
            this.businessImage = businessImage;
            console.log(businessImage);
        });
    }
}
```

this is the template

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>

<div *ngFor="let questions of businessImage">
    <h1>{{questions.question}}</h1>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let answers of questions">
            {{answers.answer}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

That's the way it's always worked when doing it any other time.  I also tried `let question of businessImage.questions` with both `{{question}}` and `{{questions.question}}`.  Either way I get an undefined error on `questions`.

I went through the interfaces adding a 1 to them just to see if it broke the data to make sure those were doing there job and things weren't just bypassing it going strait into the OnInit.  I messed with the `businessImage: bus_image` part to see if that messed with the `console.log()` to make sure it was receiving the data to deploy into the template.

The only thing I can think of is maybe the way firebase automatically added keys the `questions[]` and `answers[]` arrays I originally coded.  Can anyone shed some light on this?

> UPDATE

This is what I have now in my class.

```
export class AppComponent {

    title = 'app works!';
    businessImage$: Observable<bus_image>;

    constructor(private _firebaseService:FirebaseService){
        this.businessImage$ = this._firebaseService.getBusImg();
        console-log(this.businessImage$);
    }

    //ngOnInit() {
    //  this._firebaseService.getBusImg().subscribe(businessImage => {
    //      this.businessImage$ = businessImage;
    //      console.log(businessImage);
    //  });
    //}
}
```

and this is the template

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>

<div *ngFor="let questions of (businessImage$ | async)?.questions">
    <h1>{{question.question}}</h1>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let answer of questions.answers">
            {{answer.answer}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

no errors are coming up, and nothing is rendering and now the `console.log()` is showing a huge object that I can't even find the data in.

Comment: How does the service method look? How does your data actually look like? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok after a couple days of poking around reading everything I can find I came up with this solution.

I changed instances `FirebaseListObservable` to `FirebaseObjectObservable`.

Then in `app.component` I changed the

```
businessImage: bus_image;
```

part to

```
businessImage: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
```

After that I changed my template to look like this.

```
<div *ngFor="let question of businessImage?.questions">
    <h1>{{question.question}}</h1>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let answer of question.answers">
            {{answer.answer}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

after that everything worked like a charm.  Thanks to everybody who had input, it definitely helped me figure out what I needed to look into in order to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Try these possible fixes:

Use the safe navigation ("Elvis") operator in your view to make sure you don't get issues with the async data:

```
<div *ngFor="let questions of businessImage">
    <h1>{{questions?.question}}</h1>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let answers of questions">
            {{answers?.answer}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Secondly, it appears that businessImage is not an array, so it can't iterate over it (unless the async data is a list).  Define it this way:

```
businessImage: bus_image[] = []
```

If you are receiving a list.

If you are not receiving a list, then you need to change your iterator to be

```
<div *ngFor="let questions of businessImage?.questions">
```

Comment: I'm getting an error telling me bus_image can't be assigned to type bus_image[].

Answer (score 0):

My problems was with Rules permission: by default they require perms,
so modified the Firebase Rules as follows:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```